# Practice of high frequency scheduled Ansible playbook runs

Tags: ansible, scheduled-task, automation, configuration-management, best-practices

I'm fairly new to administrating servers with configuration managers such as Ansible. **I plan on running playbooks automatically on a schedule** (via something like *[Ansible Semaphore](https://docs.ansible-semaphore.com/)*, or even just Cron) **with high frequency** (like every 30 minutes or so).

I'm hoping to achieve two goals with this approach:

1. Enforce configuration (so I can be confident that no deviation from the expected configuration exists for long);
2. Detect any such deviation and investigate it (since Ansible reports changes for each task).

**Is this a normal and/or recommended approach** (I wasn't able to find authoritative sources on the best practices in this regard)?

If not, why, — and what would be a better way to achieve my goals?

Thank you!

Comment: See [UBUNTU20-CIS](https://github.com/ansible-lockdown/UBUNTU20-CIS) for an example of configuring and auditing systems. Use [ansible-runner](https://ansible.readthedocs.io/projects/runner/en/stable/) to schedule the playbooks on your own. See the [example](https://ansible-runner-role.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example1-cron.html).

Comment: @VladimirBotka, thanks a lot for the helpful recommendations. Especially for mentioning CIS configuration. Now I know what my next project will be =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ansible AWX](https://www.ansible.com/products/awx-project/faq) and [Ansible Tower](https://www.ansible.com/products/controller), both have the capability to [Schedule](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/scheduling.html) [Job Templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html).

Since Ansible Managed Nodes are agent-less, Ansible pushes the configuration which is described with a playbook from the Control Node onto the Remote Nodes. Therefore you need at least to consider

- How long will the runtime for my playbook be?
- How many nodes should become configured and the configuration enforced?
- What could be resource constrains like network bandwith, hops, latency, utilization, etc.?

but that should be the same for any other product.

You could start with reviewing [Task engine built on top of Ansible (AWX)](https://github.com/ansible/awx) and read further about [Ansible Tower for Configuration Drift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71251713/6771046) or [Control with Ansible Tower](https://www.ansible.com/blog/control-with-ansible-tower-part-1). And also do not miss the comment from Vladimir Botka about

> *[UBUNTU20-CIS](https://github.com/ansible-lockdown/UBUNTU20-CIS) for an example of configuring and auditing systems. Use `ansible-runner` to schedule the playbooks on your own. See the [Example](https://ansible-runner-role.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example1-cron.html).*

Comment: AWX too complex  for this task, Semaphore better choice.

Comment: Agree - the runtime of the playbook in question is usually the biggest limiting factor for  determining how frequently the playbook can be re-run.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, just to clarify, in a server environment, it's A-okay to run playbooks as often as possible based on the observed execution time (plus some margin, of course)?

Comment: Yes, of course. See in example [Control with Ansible Tower](https://www.ansible.com/blog/control-with-ansible-tower-part-1) to prevent Configuration Drift or [Ansible Tower for Configuration Drift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71251713/6771046).

Comment: @U880D Don't have enough reputation to upvote anything, but I'm certainly grateful for your help! Cheers!